# CoreData - get relationship in ViewWillAppear to count it

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Not sure why this is causing me so much grief but, here it goes:

I want badges on all tableViewCells containing relational data.
The first view of my app uses a fetchedResultsController to populate tableViewCells with team names. I want the badge to show the number of athletes associated to each team.
I’m trying to pull the relationship to count it for each team in the viewWillAppear method.
I want to do something like:

```
Team *team = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *counted = [team.athletes count];
```

But this does not work in ViewWillAppear because I don’t have a declared indexPath and am not sure how to do that. This has got to be one the simplest things to do but it throws me for a loop everytime I’m faced with it.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide a code for table view delegates. cellForIndexpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (or perhaps `configureCell:forIndexPath:` which is often used to combine a fetched results controller with a table view).

Please note that `[team.athletes count]` returns an `int`, not an `NSString`, so you probably want

```
NSString *counted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [team.athletes count]];
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I was so stuck on having this code in ViewWillAppear/ViewWillLoad... I Added your suggestion into cellForRowAtIndexPath and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!